# How to modify files in one local branch and switch to another local branch without merging changes?

Tags: git

I've been struggling with this for a while. Here's the scenario:

I'm on a main branch (there's both local and remote) and I've made some changes. But I don't want those changes on the main branch. So, I create a new branch with something like 'git checkout -b new-branch'. Now I'm in the new branch with the same unstaged files that have been modified. So then I stage the files in that new branch and switch back to the main branch.

The problem is now an automatic merge takes place and stages the changes I made to new-branch and merges them into main. Ugh!

Is there a way that I can keep file changes separate between branches while switching back and forth? What is the easiest way to do this?

Here are the steps to see what's happening:

1. in current branch, make a change to a file
2. create a new local branch with git: 'git checkout -b new-branch'
3. unstaged file with changes still exists
4. stage the changed file git command 'git add .'
5. switch back to the original branch with git command: 'git checkout -'
6. See the staged file from the new branch carry over to the current branch

Edit: it was already pointed out that the changes need to be committed to the new branch to prevent it from having this 'carryover' behavior since git uses the same index no matter what branch you're on.

Comment: Why not just commit those files on the new branch before switching back to the main branch? Also, I am a little unsure about that "automatic merge". Can you show us the exact commands you're running and the associated output?

Comment: If you need that on a more regular base, I suggest you look into git workspaces. And if you want to follow up here: no, there shouldnt be auto-merging. So please provide a [mcve] with a real example.

Comment: See Mark Adelsberger's answer

Comment: Hi, rather than editing the question and adding comments once you have a satisfactory answer, the convention in this site is to mark the correct answer as "accepted" (using the tick mark next to the vote counts). The question can then stay as just a question, but the site will show it as "answered" in searches.

Answer (score 4):

> The problem is now an automatic merge takes place and stages the changes I made to new-branch and merges them into main. Ugh!

No, that is not what happens.

What happens is that since you didn't commit the changs, and that means they're still in the index, and there is only one index (not 1 per branch), the changes come with you, just like they did when you switched to the new branch with them in the worktree.

If you want the changes to be associated with the branch, commit them.  Then when you switch back to `main` they won't follow you.

For completeness, I'll mention that you *can* create separate indexes (and worktrees) per branch with the `git worktree` command, but that's probably not what you awnt to do (as it will make switching branches more of a hassle).

Comment: Being fairly new to git, I wasn't sure how the indexing worked. The reason I like to stage them is so that they're not committed (yes, must be the way I'm thinking). Why commit when you're not finished with the changes? That's why I thought staging them would be a safe way to kind of "backup work" that's unfinished and then switch to another branch to work on something else. So what do you typically do for that use case? Do you commit them anyway?

Comment: It almost makes me feel guilting committing unfinished code because it shows up in the log when pushed to the remote branch. I don't really want to pollute the history with unfinished work

Comment: You can amend commits.  Or you can use rebase to squash commits.  Basically a commit doesn't have to be "permanent".  That said, if a branch has been pushed, then there are good reasons not to remove commits that have already been pushed as part of that branch's history - but even then, if you were working on a branch, there's no reason those commits ever have to be merged back into any other branch

Comment: So given my use case, let's say I finished the changes in the new branch and then want to merge them into the main branch. Would cherry picking be the best option if I don't want the full log from the other branch? Or is there some other way to merge in the changes and have it appear as only one commit in main branch's log?

Comment: No.  Cherry picking is for when you don't want all the changes.  You can amend the commit instead of making a distinct commit after it (see the `git commit` docs); or you can squash the commits with rebase (see the `git rebase` docs) or witha "squash merge" (see the `git merge` docs).  There's really more ivolved here than can be clearly explained in comments; and it's also not really the same question anymore; so if you still need assistance after looking over the documentation, I would post another question